# How to get a set of values through a foreign key and many to many relationship?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following models.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(
        Topping,
        blank=True,
        through='PizzaTopping'
    )

    locations = models.ManyToManyField(
        Location,
        blank=True,
        through='PizzaLocations'
    )

class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(
        Pizza,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    topping = models.ForeignKey(
        Topping,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class PizzaLocations(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(
        Pizza,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Topping(models.Model):
    topping = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True)
```

I would like to do this query:

```
Get the most popular toppings where location = some location
```

I understand I need to do something like:

- Filter the pizzas by location
- Get the toppings used in all those pizzas
- Order by most frequent toppings

But I'm getting totally confused.

Could you please help explain how to construct such a complex query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
Topping.objects.filter(pizza__locations__location='Location Name').annotate(count=Count("id")).order_by('-count')
```